# Use of KeyStore in SSL LoadBalancers

Tags: ssl, load-balancing

I have a service running on fleet of machines behind a load balancer. The load balancer is binded with an SSL certificate. If I use self-signed certificate on my service, is my connection from client to load balancer still secured ?

If I create a keystore using the certificate binded to load balancer and ask my service to use this keystore. How does it effect the communication between client and service ?

Comment: Well-known certificates work just like self-signed certificates, except that the well-known certificates are recognized by web browsers so they do not issue warning messages to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Since the load balancer (LB) is a reverse proxy, external client wouldn't know any difference on how the communication between LB and backend was done.

Typically backend servers are isolated from the internet via firewall, hence no SSL required. However if you do need to use SSL, yes self-signed certificate will add extra security. Your colleague will no longer able to simply sniff the packets and see the information.

From security perspective, using self-signed certificate in this scenario still poses some risk. Any of your colleague with access to the private key and DNS can still launch eavesdropping attack. Furthermore it can be cumbersome having LBs to trust public key of each backends (and everytime it expires you have to redo it).

A better approach is to use an [internally managed Certification Authority (CA)](http://gerrydevstory.com/2014/01/24/internal-ssl-tls-certification-authority/). Each internally issued certs are signed by this CA. LBs only need to trust this internal CA and it will automatically trust all chained certs.

This is typically done in a large corporation with many business units with potentially conflicting interest. Since they're still one organization, all business units are on the same network, however if they sniff information exchanged by another business it can cause a legal breach. If this situation doesn't apply then you might re-think the usage of SSL for internal traffic.

Comment: If server uses self signed certificate and load balancer is binded with a certificate issued by CA. When communication starts between client and server and Client asks for signed certificate, Server responds with self signed certificate. Then whats the use of certificate binded to the load balancer ? Will the communication still be secure between load balancer and client ?

Comment: Keep in mind there are 2 different client-server communication here. 1) backend server - LB and 2) LB - user. For 1) the server is backend, the client is LB, for 2) the server is LB the client is user. What type of SSL is setup for 1) (or even if no SSL) will never affect 2) as long as it works. In order to make 1) works you have to make LB trust the self-signed cert (in context of 1) LB is the client)